# jquery - using a function id in a different function

Tags: jquery

I have a function like that:

```
function loadcategory(id) {
   jQuery("#categoryArea").load("ajax_post_category.php?catid="+id+"");
  }
```

im getting id via link like that:

```
<a href='javascript:loadcategory(".$row['catid'].");'>
```

i would like to use function loadcategory(id)'s id in a different function. for example:

```
function different() {
       jQuery("#different").load("ajax_post_category.php?catid="+loadcategory(id)+"");
      }
```

as you can see i wanted to use +loadcategory(id)+, however i havent gotten any values. well, how can i get that value by jquery? i dont know, can anyone tell me the true way?

regards

Comment: My answer is pretty speculative. If you can give more information about what you're actually trying to do, perhaps others can give a more useful answer than mine (I have to disappear, or I would check back). Good luck.

Comment: i am getting id via link by using jquery. thats okay. i can use it in only 1 place. i just wanted to use it within the other functions. well, currently i can use it only 1 place. for example: im creating a value in php ($test = 34;), and i can use that value in every places for so many times by just typing $test. thats the what i wanted to make.. thanks for your time and example.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet you give where it works:

```
<a href='javascript:loadcategory(".$row['catid'].");'>
```

...appears to be some PHP code that *generates* an `href` for an anchor tag. Specifically, it appears to output a specific ID so that the *generated* markup that goes to the browser looks like this:

```
<a href='javascript:loadcategory("foo");'>
```

Your second example:

```
jQuery("#different").load("ajax_post_category.php?catid="+loadcategory(id)+"");
```

...is using completely client-side code, and an undefined value (`id`).

To reuse the function, you'll have to either use PHP to output a different ID, or pass the ID into `different`, or otherwise ensure that some valid ID is passed into `loadcategory`. Without more information, it's hard to tell what to recommend, but *for example*, suppose you had a series of anchor tags, and each anchor tag had a `data-cat` attribute that tol dus what category to load:

```
<a href='#' data-cat="foo">
<a href='#' data-cat="bar">
<a href='#' data-cat="baz">
```

Then you could hook up a handler to them that called `loadcategory` using those values:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('a[data-cat]').click(function() {
        loadcategory($(this).attr('data-cat'));
        return false;
    });
 });
```

That works by finding all anchor tags that have a `data-cat` attribute, hooking their `click` event, and when it occurs getting the `data-cat` attribute and calling `loadcategory` with that value.

That's a guess at what you want to do, but hopefully of some use.

Comment: `<a href='#'>`? A ferret somewhere just had a heart attack ;)

Comment: @karim79: That's standard practice so that clicking the link is harmless if JavaScript is disabled. Note that I'm cancelling the default action in the handler if JavaScript is enabled.

Comment: I know, but it could also be `<a href="you-need-js.html">`. I've voted this up too.

Comment: @karim79: Fair 'nuff. Personally, I try to avoid having these at all. If something is a link, I make it a link (by actually having the hash mean something); if not, I'll add it via JavaScript at runtime, as a link if I want what the browser will bring to that, or as something else if I don't, so that I know that JavaScript is enabled.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - To be honest, I think I was just whining. I use hashes by themselves too, and for some strange reason I decided to take it out on you :( `<bows head in shame>`.